# Make contact form for iOS app with Swift and PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, contact-form

I want to create a contact form where the user can leave me a message (and name and phone number…) and send it to me.

But I don't know how to do this because I never dealt with thinks like this before.

My own suggestion is to $_POST the content from TextField and TextView to a PHP script on my server. This will handle the content. (Either send an email to me with mail() or store it in a file on the server. The PHP script is no problem for me.)

Is that way reasonable? What is the common way to do that, to leave a feedback or something like this to the developer?

P.S. I know there's a way that the user sends me an email from inside the app. But I don't like this way.

Answer (score 0):

That seems reasonable to me. You could just write a function in swift to send to send get or post parameters like so:

```
func postParamRequest(resourceURL: String, postData: String, completionHandler: ((NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void)) {

    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: resourceURL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
        completionHandler(response, data, error)
    })

}
```

You can then just call that function and get the callback of the response, data, and any errors too (the `postData` should be `[key: value]`) for the POST parameters. Like so:

```
postParamRequest("theUrlToYourScript", postData: "key1=value&key2=value&key3=value") { (response, data, error) in
            print(data)
}
```

In your PHP script you could then retrieve the data with something like this: `$_POST["paramName"]`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I don't really understand the code. What is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @David it's saying that the http request should be a form encoded (post parameters) like an html form would send. You're just giving instructions to the page that the request is form parameters.

Comment: I made the user interface in my ViewController and I made some outlets like this: `@IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!`. I also added your code under this action connected with the submit button in the UI: `@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject)`

Comment: But how to get the content to `$_POST`? And where define the path/hyperlink to the PHP script?

Comment: @David this is a function to send parameter requests. You should just call it in the outlet function

Comment: @David define the path as the resource url parameter

Comment: Hi @Nucl3ic, sorry for my late answer. I still didn't get it work. I posted my code here: `https://codeshare.io/HKIRE`. Have I done it the right way?